# how to convert words back from next line?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

How do i convert these letters back?

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

into

```
ABCDEFG
```

I have a very long list of letters like this and it's very hard to read i want it to be in a line only, can this be possible?

Comment: Is there any marking of the words end like a blank line?

Comment: Without a fix length or a capital for each word in your letter list (upper and lower case) you have to use the solution below and to straighten the resulting line by a  line feed for your words.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Make sure you have checked `Regular expression`.

`\R` stands for any kind of line break (ie. `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`)